# Real Push Service over http

Tags: websocket, push-notification, push

i have to write a real push service and the last time i had to do something like that was a few years before. So now i´m reading about websocket connections using tcp.

My Questions: 
What is actually the best way to do this? 
Which frameworks are you using?
Is Websocket Connection really working in Company Networks with hard Firewall restrictions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: if by "writing a real push service" you mean writing your own framework on top of WebSocket - don't! Others have done it, and you're more than likely to find something that fits your needs. (My personal suggestion is to use WAMP libraries, see http://wamp.ws/implementations for an overview - there's support for quite a few languages and integration with some frontend frameworks.)

Regarding WebSocket working in corporate environments: You can use secure WebSockets, i.e. WebSockets over TLS. If TLS connections are not touched by the firewall, then this should work.